# Терминал Linux, системные вызовы, нити, ошибки при компиляции

Tags: linux, c, pthread, mutex

Извиняюсь за формат, но пишу на физтеховском серваке  на windows через виртуальную машину с Linux, поэтому только скринами могу код показать.

Краткая постановка задачи: 
Написать программу, передающую файл между двумя созданными нитями, с использованием только mutex'ов как средств синхронизации. Пользоваться иными средствами синхронизации и busy-loop'ом нельзя!

Требования: 
・Первая нить только читает информацию из входного файла 
・Вторая нить только пишет информацию в выходной файл

Ошибки пр компиляции:
[image: Ошибки выскакивающие при компиляции программы]

Сама программа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `fread` и `fwrite` — стандартные функции Си; используй другие имена.

Answer (score 2):

- В стандартной библиотеке С имена `fread` и `fwrite` уже "заняты".
- Вы пытаетесь применять оператор `->` к объекту типа `struct buf`, что является полной бессмыслицей. О чем вам и говорит открытым текстом компилятор. Что странно, у вас в некоторых строчках используется оператор `.`, а в некоторых внезапно ни с того ни с его `->`. Чего вы пытались добиться этой мешаниной из `.` и `->`?

  Судя по всему, параметром функции у вас задуман `struct buf *ptr`, а не `struct buf ptr`.
- [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html) не допускает прямого копирования объектов типа `pthread_mutex_t`

  > There are no defined comparison or assignment operators for the types pthread_attr_t, pthread_cond_t, pthread_condattr_t, pthread_mutex_t, pthread_mutexattr_t, pthread_rwlock_t and pthread_rwlockattr_t.

  То есть ваша попытка передавать ваш `struct buf` по значению и затем работать с хранящимися в полученной копии мьютексами обречена на провал.

  После исправления параметра функции на `struct buf *ptr` эта проблема исчезнет, но она же также присутствует в функции `main`: вы там смело присваиваете объекты типа `pthread_mutex_t` друг другу.
- Функция потока должна иметь тип `void * (void *)`. Вы же подсовываете в `pthread_create` функции типа `void * (struct buf)`. Ваши функции потока должны выглядеть примерно так

  ```
  void *my_fwrite(void *param)
  {
    struct buf *ptr = param;
    // И далее уже работаем через `ptr`
    ...
  ```
- Ваша функция `main` запускает потоки, после чего сразу закрывает файлы и завершает выполнение. А кто вам сказал, что к этому моменту потоки уже успели сделать свои дела? Вы закрываете файлы в то время, когда они еще могут быть нужны потокам. Более того, завершение главного потока (`main`) просто убьет все остальные потоки и процесс.

  Ваша функция `main` должна ждать завершения работы потоков и только после этого закрывать файлы и завершаться.